# multiple function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use multiple function in a script.i am not getting calculated value in second textbox. i dont know what is wrong in my program. 
returning no value.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
function fun1()
{
    var z=5;
    function fun3(x)
    {
        alert("i am fun3");
        var y=x+z;  
    }
    return y;
}
function fun2()
{   
    var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    var result = fun3(a);
    document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML=result;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter no: <input type="text" value="" id="txt1" onkeydown="fun2();">
Result: <input type="text" value="" id="txt2" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fun3` can't be called from `fun2` because it is defined in `fun1` and therefore only available in that scope. Move it beside `fun1`/`fun2`

Comment: u r right but actually requirement is like .. i have some value in fun2(). and  some value in fun3().  task is to calculate both values  and to get result in textbox2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
  function fun1(a)
    {
        var z=5, y;
        function fun3(x)
        {
            alert("i am fun3");
            y=x+z;  
        }
        fun3(a)
        return y;
    }
    function fun2()
    {   
        var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        var result = fun1(a);
        document.getElementById("txt2").value=result;
    }
```

**EDIT :**

I changed : `document.getElementById("txt2").innerHtml=result;` with `document.getElementById("txt2").value=result;` as txt2 is an [input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)
If not, please precise your question, I'll edit it as soon as I've more details.

**EDIT 2**

@Nitish finished by found by himself : [jsfiddle.net/nitishkaushik/4sxb9d55/4](http://jsfiddle.net/nitishkaushik/4sxb9d55/4)

Comment: sir i want (a+z) in 2nd textbox.and condition is,
value of a is in fun2(). and value of z is in fun1().

Comment: but result is not calculated as we press key...can u do it in jsfeedle

Comment: when press 2 in firsttextbox,output should be 7, again when press 4 in first textbox output should be 9

Comment: got my answer....i modify your code a little bit more... your code was very helpfull tanx :)

Comment: Could you give a JSFiddle link then I edit my post quoting you to have a complete answer for people coming next time ?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i want. and i got it. if anybody want then they can use :)

Enter no: 
    Result:

```
<script>
function fun1(a)
{
    alert("Debugging 1st level="+a);
    var z=5, y;
    function fun3(x)
    {
    alert("Debugging 2nd level="+x);
         y= (parseInt(x) + parseInt(z));  
    alert("Debugging 3rd level="+y);
    }
    fun3(a)
    return y;
}

function fun2(val)
{   var result=0;

    alert("value is"+val);
    var result = fun1(val);
    alert("Debugging 4th level="+result);
    document.getElementById("txt2").value=result;
}

</script>
```